# How to setup Mac OS Snow Leopard to Alert me When My Battery is Full?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, battery

When the battery is low, Mac OS alerts me to plug it into the power supply.

But, how to setup to alert me when the battery is full?

Comment: Why do you want to know when it's full?

Comment: And, some full Apple batteries are more full than others: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1909 ;-)

Comment: I can envision waiting for the battery to be full before grabbing the laptop for a trip.  I don't want to keep checking, just hear a mechanical voice say "Battery full".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MiniBatteryStatus](http://www.emeraldion.it/software/widgets/minibatterystatus.html) widget.

It will [growl](http://growl.info/) when the battery is full.

But you can also set it up to growl when you switch between battery and AC power. Or when you need to be warned when the battery charge percentage goes lower some value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "state of the battery" to the menu bar (this can be set in the prefs panels - energy saver / second tab). Then an icon (and/or some text) will display the % of his power (on the top right corner of the main menu bar, next to the date). When it's totaly recharged, the icon will change.
Another way is to (phicaly) push on the button on the battery itself. There are 5 led's that will or won't blink. If all the five leds are lit, that means that your battery in totaly "fully" recharged.

Comment: You could also write a script to fire off an AppleScript dialog box, but who cares: Charging your battery should be a passive activity.

Comment: @Nerdling, now that you've released the AppleScript horse: *how*?

Comment: @Pierre Thanks, but those options aren't alerts. I want to be alerted with Growl or an Popup, or something like.

Comment: @Daniel : A plugin would be to ask your little brother to blow in a horn when the status bar shows 100 %. (He'll do it for a few dollars)